# Device driver compilation error on linux

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-device-driver

I have started writing device driver and written first character driver and got the compilation error:

```
    scripts/Makefile.build:44: /home/betatest/Public/Device-Driver-Test/first-driver/Makefile: No such file or directory
    make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/betatest/Public/Device-Driver-Test/first-driver/Makefile'.  Stop.
    Makefile:1448: recipe for target '_module_/home/betatest/Public/Device-Driver-Test/first-driver' failed
    make[1]: *** [_module_/home/betatest/Public/Device-Driver-Test/first-driver] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64'
    makefile:19: recipe for target 'default' failed
    make: *** [default] Error 2
```

My make file name is "**makefile**"?
while studying makefile it is written that default name of makefile can be **Makefile** or **makefile** it does not make difference for make utility. Does the name matters for device drivers makefile ? Should the name of make file for device driver compulsorily be "**Makefile**"? If so why?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: With the -f option you can use any name. Otherwise you must use the default name

Comment: What is default name of make file for device driver code? make -f makefile I have tried but still the same error.

Comment: What is line 44 of scripts/Makefile.build?

Comment: Kernel build directory has a make file of that name. No error from there.

Comment: The error is from there. It is telling you it is on line 44. Do you think it is lying to you?

Answer (score 1):

The script is not running make with a default name. The script is giving `-f /home/betatest/Public/Device-Driver-Test/first-driver/Makefile` which does not exist.

Comment: Below is the output of `ls` command : <br/>                                        [mypc@myos first-driver]$ ls <br/>
first-driver.c  makefile <br/>

Comment: And if you ran make in that directory it would find it by default name. If you run make from another directory and give the -f option then it finds a specific file.

Answer (score 1):

> while studying makefile it is written that default name of make file can be Makefile or makefile it does not make difference for make utility

True enough. When you invoke the `make` command, it knows to look for either of `Makefile` or `makefile`.

But there could be other reasons why you are seeing this error. It is possible that the script invokes `make` with an explicit `-f` argument to look for a `Makefile`. Take a look at line `44` in `scripts/Makefile.build`.

Answer (score 1):

[What Name to Give Your Makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Makefile-Names.html)

When you use `make` utility it will search in order as GNUmakefile, makefile and Makefile.First name is not recommended as it should be used when GNU make utility is used. For non-standard name of makefile you can specify --file or -f with `make` utility.

Its seems that line `44` has error .Try to compile that `makefile` with `-f` option.